# wide sense stationary process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

I am a beginner in probability theory, and have a very basic and limited understanding of the random processes, but interested in understanding them more.

In case of wide sense stationary processes, what is the benefit of "relaxing" the the strict sense stationary rule by limiting time shift invariance to only bivariate joint distributions? In other words, what is the "gain" in not requiring the time shift invariance rule with the trivariate joint distributions (or may be even the higher order multivariate joint distributions) of the elements of the random process in the wide sense stationary process definition?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The point is that in the case of normal (Gaussian) processes, i.e. all finite dimensional distributions are normal, wide sense stationary processes are also strict sense stationary. Normal processes are the most used model of stochastic processes.

Further a number of techniques (least square f.e.) depend only on the first two moments of the processes, so one can prove more general results for wide sense stationary processes without requiring strict stationarity.

Comment: Thanks but my question is more basic. In a weak stationary process by requiring that the bivariate (and not trivariate) joint distribution remains same for any particular time shift, what are we trying to say? I am looking for something of an intuitive explanation of weak stationary process and the basis for requiring bivariate joint distribution and not trivariate or other higher level multivariate distributions (like in the case of strict sense stationary processes) to be invariate for any particular time shift.

Comment: For a normal process from the time invariance of bivariate distributions follows the time invariance of all higher-dimensional joint distributions.